# Charles Proxy Issue on Andy emulator( Failure:SSLHandshake: Unsupported curveId: 29 )

Tags: android, ssl, charles-proxy, andyroid

I am trying to do a debug session on an App (Android) by monitoring the outbound/inbound HTTP traffic on Andy emulator.For SSL traffic I get following error :
`Failure: SSLHandshake: Unsupported curveId: 29`

In the past I was not receiving above error using that app .Could you guys tell me what this error means and how to fix it?Is there any problem within the app that causes to receive SSL error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the Android section in their documentation https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates

You need to add a network security config file for Android N and higher devices.

Comment: Thanks for replies. If the app is tested on lower android version do i still need network security ?I am currently testing the app on android 5.1.1 device and still get this error!

Answer (score 0):

From Android N+, we have to add the Certificate in your app in `network_security_config.xml` and `manifest.xml` in order to intercept the HTTPS Traffic.

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<network-security-config>
<debug-overrides>
<trust-anchors>
<!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
<certificates src="user" />
</trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... >
...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the quick tutorial: https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device